# Listen for thread while executing task

Tags: python, multithreading, process

I tried to look for an answer, but couldn't find anything relevant. Hence, the decision to ask.

I have a script A. At the beginning of script A, it calls script B (or a function, either works) in a separate thread.

A continues to do some task. I want to continue executing script A till script B doesn't finish.

How do I listen for the finishing of B while continuing with tasks of A?

For example,

```
Call Script B using subprocess, import file and run function (either way)
while(1):
   count=count+1
   if script B ended:
        break
```

Can anyone illustrate how to check the "script B ended" part?

Comment: How are you calling script B? Are you calling it using a separate thread or a separate process?

Comment: It calls another function which uses subprocess to call that script. (I'm open to changing that if it can help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really simple way to do what you want:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def stupid_work():
    time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=stupid_work)
    t.start()
    while 1:
        if not t.is_alive():
            print 'thread is done'
            break # or whatever
        else:
            print 'thread is working'    

        time.sleep(1)
```

The thread will die when it's done, so you just check intermittently to see if it's still around. You did not mention you want a return value. If you do, then you can pass the target function a queue, and replace `if not t.is_alive()` with `if not q.empty()`. Then do a `q.get()` to retrieve the return value when it's ready. And be sure to have the target put the return value in the queue, or you'll be waiting for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot upvote you because of my reputation being low (I need 15). But I'll remember to upvote as soon as I gain some. That as exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot for the extra information on the returning value as well. I might require that at somepoint in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the subprocess module you can do something like this.

```
from subprocess import Popen
proc = Popen(["sleep", "100"])

while True:
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        print("proc is done")
        break
```

More on subprocess and poll [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).